# Bootstrap 4 in angular 6, javascript components

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I run: `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` for installing the the javascript components, and got this:

> npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

and

> npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.3 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

but the good new is:

> - @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 added 1 package from 1 contributor in 11.948s

So what does it means? should I be worried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I be worried?

No. The jquery and popper js dependencies are only necessary if you use the JS part of Bootstrap. But ng-bootstrap's goal is precisely to **replace** this jquery-based JavaScript code with native Angular components, that do not depend on anything other than Angular (and RxJS, but Angular also depends on it).

So you should just ignore these two warnings. Bootstrap is needed by ng-bootstrap because it uses the Bootstrap CSS to implement its components and directives. But it doesn't use its JS code.

Comment: Thanks, I include your answer in a [Post](https://josuevalrob.com/angular6-bootstrap4)

Answer (score 1):

It means you have to install `jQuery` as well as Bootstrap JS relies on it, unless you are not going to use anything but pure Bootstrap's CSS.